# Optimización de consulta

Tags: sql, xml, cast

Al consultar un campo con tipo de dato xml el tiempo estimado de ejecucion es de 3:45 minutos.

```
SELECT
    nombre,
    usuario,
    tipoDocumento,
    extencion,
    base64
FROM
    OPENQUERY([server], 'SELECT nombre, usuario, tipoDocumento, extencion, cast(base64 as varchar(max)) as base64 FROM INGRESOS.dbo.Documentos')
```

Ya realice pruebas omitiéndolo de la consulta y el tiempo de respuesta mejora considerablemente.

```
SELECT
    nombre,
    usuario,
    tipoDocumento,
    extencion
FROM
    OPENQUERY([server], 'SELECT nombre, usuario, tipoDocumento, extencion FROM INGRESOS.dbo.Documentos')
```

Tendrán alguna sugerencia de como convertir el tipo de dato para agilizar la cnsulta?

Comment: Usando OPENQUERY es casi imposible optimizar una consulta. Es peor cuando no tienes ninguna condición.

Comment: _ya realicé pruebas omitiéndolo_ <-- a quién? pon la prueba en la pregunta